# How to create a sub-theme SASS Bootstrap 3.4.1 for Drupal 8.7?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal, drupal-8

How to create a sub-theme SASS Bootstrap 3.4.1 for Drupal 8.7 ?

My server is on Ubuntu 18.04

The steps are described here, but I do not understand all the steps :

https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8.x-3.x

I installed the Drupal Bootstrap theme :

https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap

I created my sub-theme, no problem :

https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8.x-3.x#starterkit

I downloaded the SASS source files, no problem :

https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8.x-3.x#source

I have to download Drupal startup styles, no problem :

https://github.com/unicorn-fail/drupal-bootstrap-styles

Here is the structure of my directory :

[image]

**Now what should I do ?**

What are the following steps to use the following Bootswatch theme and to compile :

https://bootswatch.com/3/flatly/

I want to apply to the previous theme, the colors of the following theme :

https://bootswatch.com/3/sandstone/

Comment: Did you make your theme the active theme?

Comment: @2pha yes. How to compile and add bootswatch?

Comment: Compile with a [local sass compiler](https://drupal-bootstrap.org/api/bootstrap/docs!Sub-Theming.md/group/sub_theming/8.x-3.x#sass)

Comment: Usyally when I have subthemed this the bootstrap 3 theme, I have just used the CDN option and overridden styles with standard CSS as nessesary.

Comment: @2pha I have to use the compiler to change all the colors of the theme. Otherwise it makes a lot of code in css. How to install in compiler, which to install. There is nothing in the Drupal Bootstrap documentation

Comment: The compiler is to compile the styles (less or scss) into css. It has nothing to do with Drupal so has no docs for it. There is plenty of info to be found on google or the bootstrap website.

Comment: @2pha Thanks I have to install which command-line compiler for bootstrap 3.4.1 on ubuntu?

Comment: https://sass-lang.com/install